# Add and Remove Class when a div is toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Hi i have a problem with my code, i have a menu and a map in my page, when the page loads the map has `col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10`, because my menu is open, when i close the menu i made that the map changes to `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12`, and it works fine but when i reopen the menu it doesn't change the class to `col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10`.

This is the code that i tried

UPDATE

Thanks everyone for your answers, I've added the `==` but now it only puts the `col-lg-10` class

```
 function MapSize() {
        var shown = document.getElementById("containerForm");
        var map = document.getElementById("containerMap");

        if (shown.style.display == "none") {

            map.className = "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";


        } else if (shown.style.display == "block") {
            map.className += "col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10";
        }
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Change `=` to `===`.  Single equals is assignment, not equality.

Comment: Kindly add your html.Your operators really you should us ==

Comment: All of the answers (so far) are telling you to use `==` — except @Taplar, who has it right.  You should use `===` ([strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)) unless you have a very good (and well understood) reason to use `==` (loose equality) which does automatic type-coercion.

Comment: In addition to changing `=` to `==` or `===`, your `map.className = xxx` overwrites the original classes...

Comment: Good job making the new changes. One thing you might want to check is whether the `style=display:block` is explicitly set on your `shown` element. I tried the code with a div, which has display block as it's default behavior, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operators in your if statement.

Instead of having

`if (shown.style.display = "none")`

it should be

`if (shown.style.display == "none")`

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator instead of comparison in your if:

```
 if (shown.style.display = "none") {
```

Use `==`

Comment: Use `===` unless you have a very good (and well understood) reason to use `==`

Answer (score 0):

```
function MapSize() {

        var shown = document.getElementById("containerForm");
        var map = document.getElementById("containerMap");

        if (shown.style.display == "none") {

            map.className = "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";


        } else if (shown.style.display == "block") {
            map.className = "col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10";
        }
    }
```

There are more than 1 problems:

1) use `===` for equality check
`if (shown.style.display === "none")` should be if `(shown.style.display === "none")`

2) When you do `map.className = "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";` Your old classes `col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10` is gone. You can open chrome dev tools to check the classname.

Use `map.className +=` instead of `map.className =`

3)Is `map.className.remove` a function? Please open the dev tool to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function MapSize() {
    var shown = document.getElementById("containerForm");
    var map = document.getElementById("containerMap");

    map.className = (shown.style.display === "none") ? "col-lg-12" : "col-lg-10";
}
```

BTW, in bootstrap 3 class `"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"` is equal to `"col-lg-12"` for the case as well as `"col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10"` equal to `"col-lg-10"`